# Not able to find SMS_DP_smspkg$ in Distribution point

Tags: sccm

When I checked the CAS Log, it mentioned package:

> Download location found 0 - http://XXYY.CORP.ZZ.ORG/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/CSS013F5

I logged to the DP XXYY.CORP.ZZ.ORG and searched for folder SMS_DP_SMSPKG$, but I'm not able see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a folder, but rather an Application on a Site in the IIS WebServer on your DP.

to see where it leads you have to open the "Server Manager", go to "Roles" --> "Web Server (IIS) --> "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" then on the right pane open your DP. then open "Sites" --> "Default Website" and there you should see "SMS_DP_SMSPKG$". If you now click on it and select "Basic Settings" to the far right you can locate the "Physical Path"

[image]

I think it always points to the same path as the hidden local share \\localhost\SCCMContentLib$ (which can be accessed by typing this in the windows explorer address bar, but will not reveal the physical location just jump there.

[image]
By default it will be a folder SCCMContentLib in one of your root drives (normally not C: but the first one after, but it depends on your configuration, it will be the first drive alphabetically where no file "NO_SMS_ON_DRIVE.SMS" exists in the root, afaik)

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMCHT.jpg)

I got the package location from folder DataLib